# How to properly apply Benford's Law to apartment service charge data?

Tags: distributions, fraud-detection

I want to apply [Benford's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law) to a breakdown of billing information we recieve for our apartment building's service charges. In other words, I want to compare the distribution of my service charge numbers to Benford's Law distribution.

Long story short, the residents and I believe there is either some fraud or negligence occuring with the billing amounts and no one can help us resolve our case.

The service charge breakdown will look something like this

```
Service                     | Year 2021
----------------------------------------
Estate CCTV Maintenance     | $4.09
Estate Reparis              | $30.25
Grounds Maintenance         | $45.25
Elevator Maintenance        | $258.89
Heating / Hot Water         | $27.35
Reserve Fund                | $819.59
..........
```

There are about 21 services in total (I've only shown 6 above). Each of the residents is charged a slightly different amount per service based on the size (sq. ft) of their apartment, and there are some 50 residents, yielding $21\times 50 = 1,050$ unique data points.

I know that to apply Benford's Law, you need a dataset that ranges over a few orders of magnitude. Unfortunately, here we only have numbers from $10^{-1} \sim 10^3$.

I have a few questions

1. Is $1,050$ enough datapoints to compare the distribution of these service charge numbers to Benford's Law log distribution? How can I account for any error?
2. Is the range of this dataset large enough to use Benford's Law?
3. Can I apply Benford's Law to the leading digit of the of the number, as well as to the leading digit of the decimal in each charge separately?

Comment: Sure, you can *apply* Benford's Law.  What matters is how you interpret it: if you reject the null hypothesis, it is not legitimate to attribute that to "fraud or negligence."  There are plenty of benign alternative explanations.

Comment: It sounds like you might know the formula that allocates the total cost of some service (e.g. grounds maintenance) to residents based on their square footage. It should then be easy to check whether that formula is being followed. So then you would just be analyzing data on the service level (50 data points) instead of the service-resident level (1050 data points).

Comment: It partly depends on the spread of the charges between the different apartments:  if they all paid  $\$4.09$ for CCTV maintenance, and similarly the other items, then you really only have $21$ observations.  If they are slightly spread out then you still have an issue, while if they are widely spread then this goes away

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, because different categories for your data is equivalent to spanning orders of magnitude, in terms of diversification of the data. For the type of statistical significance test, I would use Cho and Gaines (2007) Euclidean distance d*N. Morrow (2014) reviews all available tests, and concludes that the convergence of d*N is better than the others.

Morrow, J. (2014). [Benford’s Law, families of distributions and a test basi](https://cep.lse.ac.uk/_new/publications/abstract.asp?index=4486)s [Paper]. Centre for Economic Performance, London School of Economics and Political Science.